# Automatically Extract Text from any app using Tasker

Tags: tasker, automation, copy-paste

I've recently started playing with automation of simple routines in my Android device, and I've encountered an issue I cannot seem to solve.

What I need is a way to detect if a change to the **Clipboard** has been made (preferably after I copy a piece of text from anywhere), and automatically paste that text to any app of my choice (either **Evernote** or **Keep**, doesn't really matter).

Is there any way to open an app using **Tasker** ONLY when a copy event was fired?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some thorough reading of the Tasker Documentation I believe I have found an elegant way to accomplish this:

[image: Basic Profile setup with the desired application]
[image: The recursive Copy Text task setup]

Basically this is a recursive task, constantly checking against a variable called %CLIPTEXT that it is equal to %CLIP (which is a predefined variable containing the contents of the Clipboard) and acting upon accordingly if it is not equal (aka changed) by opening the desired app.